# Unable to add Twitter-bootstrap to grails project - Beginner

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, grails

Under `BuildCOnfig.groovy` i added the following

```
plugins {
     ...
     runtime ":twitter-bootstrap:3.0.3"
     ...
}
```

Thereafter, i edited my `index.html` code to like like follows (I found this code example from `bootstrap` itself).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">

<title>Cover Template for Bootstrap</title>
<r:layoutResources/>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->



<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<r:layoutResources/>
    <div class="site-wrapper">

        <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

            <div class="cover-container">

                <div class="masthead clearfix">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
                        <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inner cover">
                    <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building
                        simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add
                        your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
                    <p class="lead">
                        <a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Learn more</a>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="mastfoot">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p>
                            Cover template for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>,
                            by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of grails are you using? Are you using the asset-pipeline-plugin instead of the resources-plugin? (I'm curious because your favicon points to a directory called "assets" - but this may be a coincidence)

and is the "cover.css" (last link-tag in the head) delivered correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should upgrade your version of the plugin to 3.1.1:

```
plugins {
     ...
     compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.1.1"
     ...
}
```

Second, since you are using the bootstrap plugin for Grails you need to use the resource modules to include it. Also you don't need to manually include jQuery as it will be included by the plugin. Here is a simple example of a starter template which is setup correctly for the bootstrap plugin and Grails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>My example bootstrap page</title>

    <r:require modules="bootstrap"/>
    <r:layoutResources/>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico'}">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>My fantastic site goes here.</p>
    </div>

    <r:layoutResources/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I highly recommend you read up about the [resource tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Tags/resource.html) to get an understanding of how to include assets like CSS. It's also worth noting that the [documentation](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/blob/master/README.md) for the plugin explains all of the above.

Comment: I get this warning `module not found: org.grails.plugins#twitter-bootstrap;3.1.1`

Comment: Updated the answer to use 'compile' instead of 'runtime'. You may have to clean and refresh-dependencies as well.

Comment: How do i refresh dependencies. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the app. nothing worked however.

Comment: From the grails command line run "refresh-dependencies" Alternatively exit the grails command line and start it back up and run a "clean" then "compile".

Comment: It says `grails refresh-dependencies` has encountered a problem. But when i add `compile ':twitter-bootstrap:3.0.3'` it works

Comment: It should be compile. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Well, it works for bootstrap version  `3.0.3` and not `3.1.1`